# How I can extend play 2 framework form?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4

Play 2 Framework has [Form](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Form) class in *play.api.data* package.
We can create a form with mapping in such a way:

```
Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "description" -> text
  )(Model.apply)(Model.unapply)
)
```

But what if I want to extend the Form class and to add a few methods to it?
*play.api.data.Form* is a **case** class, so I can't subclass it. Also I can't mix a trait on the fly, because form instance is creates by **apply** method of *play.api.data.Form* companion object instead of **new** keyword.

What should I do to extend this class?